# Variable from ApplicationEvents to Form?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to set a value in ComboBox based on the Windows User Name on start up.

This is what I've got in ApplicationEvents.vb:

```
Partial Friend Class MyApplication

    Public Sub MyApplication_Startup(sender As Object, e As StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
        Dim sUserNameFull As String
        If Environment.UserName = "JohnD" Then
            sUserNameFull = "John Dean"
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

And that's my Form1.vb:

```
Public Class DeskApp
Public Shared ReadOnly Property UserName As String
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    MsgBox(ApplicationEvents.sUserNameFull)

End Sub
End Class
```

How to display variable from AppEvents in this MsgBox?

And ultimately how to "push" that value into the ComboBox1?

I suppose those are the basics, but I'm really lost here.

Thanks!

Comment: Make the variable `Public Shared` and place it outside the startup event.

Comment: `Environment.UserName` can be gotten in the app/form load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is how I would do this.

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices
Namespace My
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication
        Private mUserName As String
        Public ReadOnly Property UserFullName As String
            Get
                Return mUserName
            End Get
        End Property

        Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(
            sender As Object, e As StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup

            If Environment.UserName = "JohnD" Then
                mUserName = "John Dean"
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Form code

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MsgBox(My.Application.UserFullName)
    End Sub
End Class
```